# Search tree with associative union and worst case insert/delete better than O(n)?

Tags: time-complexity, search-trees

Is there a search tree where *union* is associative, so $a \cup (b \cup c) = (a \cup b) \cup c$ gives a tree with the same structure?

A complete binary tree would be such a tree, but for example a red-black tree has several possible constructions for a given set of elements.

Is there such a tree that does better than $O(n)$ for common operations such as insert or delete?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "gives the same tree"? Does joining $a \cup b$ only work when the biggest key of $a$ is smaller than the smallest key of $b$?

Comment: @CurtisF updated the text with red-black tree as an example where it might not give the same tree.

Comment: See if the data structures in the linked duplicates meet your needs.  If not, can you edit the question to identify the specific requirements that aren't met by those approaches, clarify what you mean by "$\cup$" and "$=$" more precisely, and then flag the question for re-opening?  (It's not 100% clear to me exactly what you mean by $\cup$ and $=$.  Does $=$ mean that the trees have the same structure, or is it enough to have a hash value that lets us test whether two trees are equivalent?  Are we allowed to define the $\cup$ operator however we like?  Can you answer Curtis F's question?)

Comment: @CurtisF "Does joining a∪b only work when the biggest key of a is smaller than the smallest key of b?" no, let's say `a = fromList [1,2,3]` and `b = fromList [2,3,4]`, then `a union b = fromList [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: @D.W. I think the linked duplicates meet my needs.  Although they don't spell it out, the answer is basically NO.

Comment: @user239558, that's not how I interpret those answers.